# Which node.js based server for app store?

Tags: web-server, node.js

I recently used meteor for make a kind of 'app' store. In other words it's a website that has a similar UI/UX to Google Play, iTunes App Store, etc... There's a front page with most popular, top paid, etc. There's category pages ('games', 'etc..), there's pages about specific games.

I loved that meteor was so easy to use, get working, it's super iterative. But, now that I have it working it clearly feels like it was the wrong choice. It's very `heavy` in that it downloads js and html templates to the browser then uses websockets to send database data and renders the page. That's great if you're making gmail but it's overkill for a site that's very static. My front page only updates at most when a new app is added. Possibly less (like once a day or once a week). App pages themselves don't update unless the app is updated.

So, any suggestions for other node.js based solutions? Ideally I'd like it to be a full stack. I don't want to have to write lots of code (and therefore make lots of mistakes).  Sorry, I'm not being lazy, rather, I'm being pragmatic. For example I could query/update a database myself. Likely I'd make a few mistakes (not escaping something for example) that will bite me later. Same with say authentication and users.

Is there something else I should be looking at??